# Como especificar um espaço em branco no AWS CLI S3?

Tags: amazon-aws, cli

Uso o PowerShell ou o CMD para executar um comando no AWS CLI S3, o comando que eu executo é esse:

```
aws s3 cp s3://repositorioimagens/ampliacao/BR/1022-IKON IMAGES/STOCK239/ . --recursive
```

O problema é que quando eu tenho uma pasta com espaço em branco em algum lugar eu recebo o erro

`Unknown options: .`

Pois ele entende que eu acabei uma parte do comando e estou configurando-o (assim como acontece depois de `/STOCK239/` que eu coloco o `. --recursive`).

Como explicar para o CLI que eu quero um espaço em branco em `1022-IKON IMAGES` > `1022-IKON(ESPAÇO EM BRANCO)IMAGES`

Comment: Já tentou escapar o caractere com a barra invertida, `IKON\ IMAGES`?

Comment: Já, não funciona, o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa colocar toda string dentro de aspas duplas "".

aws s3 cp "s3://repositorioimagens/ampliacao/BR/1022-IKON IMAGES/STOCK239/" . --recursive

Comment: Valeu @Henrique, tinha descoberto mas acabei esquecendo de responder aqui. +1